# How to use Mac OS X dictionary in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, spell-checking

<strike>I know you can use Apple + control + D to check a work in cocoa eclipse.</strike> Is it possible to use the mac dictionary file for the Eclipse built-in spellchecker ( Spelling )?

Hope their is no english mistakes in this questions hahaha :P

Answer (score 5):

That is only available to cocoa based apps, as far as I'm aware Eclipse is written in Java, with a certain amount of "wrapper" going on - so even if you download the "cocoa" version, the editors where you want to use this feature wouldn't be cocoa-components.

Edit: You can find your local dictionary in ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
I'm not sure where the main dictionary is stored. You could try looking in /Library/Spelling perhaps.

Then you can point eclipse at that file, or a copy of it under Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Spelling and then select User defined dictionary.

I'd be careful using the original one though (if you find it), becuase eclipse just dumps words you add at the end of it, and the OS X one could be sorted (I'm guessing here), also eclipse expects each word to be on a new line, the OS X file might not be in the right format.

Comment: But the dictionary file, if not encrypted, could feed the eclipse spellchecker. The problem is that the eclipse dictionary is incomplete.